# Avro schema ( .avsc ) enforcement in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, avro, spark-avro

Can anyone help me with reading a avro schema (.avsc ) through Pyspark and enforcing it while writing the dataframe to a target storage ? All my targetr table schemas are provided as .avsc files and I need to provide this custom schema while saving my dataframe in Pyspark. I know there are libraries like spark-avro from databricks. But all examples are given in Scala.

Answer (score 3):

With this file `/tmp/test.avsc`

```
{
     "type": "record",
     "namespace": "com.example",
     "name": "FullName",
     "fields": [
       { "name": "first", "type": "string" },
       { "name": "last", "type": "string" }
     ]
}
```

and a dataframe like this:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([{"first": "john", "last": "parker" }], StructType([StructField("first", StringType()), StructField("last", StringType())]))
```

resulting to this:

```
+-----+------+
|first|  last|
+-----+------+
| john|parker|
+-----+------+
```

you can do this to enforce write schema:

```
jsonFormatSchema = open("/tmp/test.avsc", "r").read() 
df.write.format("avro").options(avroSchema=jsonFormatSchema).save("/tmp/avro")
```

and similiar to enforce read schema:

```
spark.read.format('avro').options(avroSchema=jsonFormatSchema).load("/tmp/avro")
```

More information is available here, where btw there are more than enough python examples: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html

Comment: I want to write as parquet and not as avro. This example is for writing as avro

Comment: well your question was how to enforce schema and I gave you the answer for that so I guess you can just ignore the writing part.